# How to convert JavaScript function to AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

JavaScript function copies text from input field to clipboard when you click button. It looks as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        'use strict';
        // click events
        document.body.addEventListener('click', copy, true);
        // event handler
        function copy(e) {
            // find target element
            var
              t = e.target,
              c = t.dataset.copytarget,
              inp = (c ? document.querySelector(c) : null);
            // is element selectable?
            if (inp && inp.select) {
                // select text
                inp.select();
                try {
                    // copy text
                    document.execCommand('copy');
                    inp.blur();
                }
                catch (err) {
                    alert('please press Ctrl/Cmd+C to copy');
                }
            }
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Usage:

```
<button id="CopyTextBtn" autofocus
        type="submit"
        class="uui-button lime-green"
        data-copytarget="#ClientsURL"
        ng-click="closeThisDialog('Cancel')">
    Copy
</button>
```

I've tried this:

```
appModule.directive('data-copytarget', function () {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element)
        {
            // click events
            document.body.addEventListener('click', copy, true);
            // event handler
            function copy(e) {
                // find target element
                var
                  t = e.target,
                  c = t.dataset.copytarget,
                  inp = (c ? document.querySelector(c) : null);
                // is element selectable?
                if (inp && inp.select) {
                    // select text
                    inp.select();
                    try {
                        // copy text
                        document.execCommand('copy');
                        inp.blur();
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        alert('please press Ctrl/Cmd+C to copy');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

But, it doesn't work.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is not a proper technical problem statement. Put a bit of effort into it. See [ask]

Comment: Of course I did it.

Comment: Huh? Did what? Sure didn't put any effort in providing a proper description with any troubleshooting info

Comment: Please, don't judge.

Comment: This is not judging. I am pointing out inadequacies in the question that make it too vague. We don't know what does or doesn't work, errors thrown or steps taken to troubleshoot etc. It is incumbent on you to clearly define a specific problem. See [ask]

Comment: JavaScript function copies text from input field to clipboard when you click button.

Comment: That explains objective but not specific problem within your code. Also would help to provide a demo

Comment: The problem is how to implement it as AngularJS directive. I'm not too much in Angular and asking for help.

Comment: Implementation is essentially correct but you haven't provided a single bit of troubleshooting detail. We shouldn't have to ask 20 questions like ... does event listener work? Are `inp` and `c` what you expect them to be? Are errors thrown? ...  etc. That's the part you should put proper effort into when asking question and providing details. Our comments shouldn't need to be longer than the text in the question

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have scope, element and attrs as argument in link function, why not use `elem.bind('click', function() { })` or you can use `angular.element(document).find('body');` and then bind the click event to it.

```
appModule.directive('data-copytarget', function () {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, elem)
        {
            // click events
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                // find target element
                var
                  t = e.target,
                  c = t.dataset.copytarget,
                  inp = (c ? document.querySelector(c) : null);
                // is element selectable?
                if (inp && inp.select) {
                    // select text
                    inp.select();
                    try {
                        // copy text
                        document.execCommand('copy');
                        inp.blur();
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        alert('please press Ctrl/Cmd+C to copy');
                    }
                }                
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The directive should copy text from input field to clipboard.

Comment: It's interesting that on button click program flow doesn't enter to directive at all.